What is Tzurah and Chomer & does it relate to mainly Olam deisgalia & Olam De Iskasia
BH
Hi,
I read in ch 26 in Tanya that if a person is going through any sort of pain it is essentially coming from the world of Olam deIskasia(the hidden world that is mainly labeled by the first two letters of Hashems name Yud Kay also on online correct me if I'm wrong saw that Olam de iskasia is the level of Atzilut and Beriya and Olam deisgalia is labeled for Olam Yetzira and Assiya) So my main question is: is tzurah and chomer the level of Olam Deisgalia and Yetzirah and Assiya although not in olam de iskasia?

@David I tried to edit your question for clarity but failed to understand it. I am posting this as an answer rather than a comment to ask you to clarify the question because of the limitations of formatting etc in comments.
The relevant passage from Chapter 26 [copied from https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7905/jewish/Chapter-26.htm] is pasted below.
Can you please refer to the wording of Chapter 26 in relation to עָלְמָא דְאִתְגַּלְיָיא and עָלְמָא דְאִתְכַּסְיָא - Olam deIskasia (the hidden spiritual world) and Olam deIsgalia (the revealed spiritual world) to explain what you mean by also online correct me if I'm wrong saw that Olam de iskasia is the level of Atzilut and Beriya and Olam deisgalia is labeled for Olam Yetzira and Assiya.
Relevant passage from Chapter 26
For it, too, is for the good, except that it is not apparent and visible to mortal eyes, for it stems from the “hidden (spiritual) world,’’ which is higher than the “revealed (spiritual) world,” whence derives an apparent and revealed good.
כִּי "גַּם זוֹ – לְטוֹבָה", רַק שֶׁאֵינָהּ נִגְלֵית וְנִרְאֵית לְעֵינֵי בָשָׂר, כִּי, הִיא מֵ"עָלְמָא דְאִתְכַּסְיָא" שֶׁלְּמַעְלָה מֵ"עָלְמָא דְאִתְגַּלְיָיא",
**The latter emanates from the letters vav and hey of Havayah ** (the Four-Letter Divine Name, composed of the letters yud-hey-vav-hey), **while the former derives from the letters yud and hey.**12 [footnote omitted]
שֶׁהוּא – ו"ה מִשֵּׁם הֲוָיָ"ה בָּרוּךְ־הוּא, וְ"עָלְמָא דְאִתְכַּסְיָא" – הוּא י"ה,
This is also the meaning of the verse, “Happy is the man whom You, G d (spelled yud hey), chasten.”13 [footnote omitted] Since the verse speaks of man’s suffering, only the letters yud and hey are mentioned.
